# What are the available SQLAlchemy methods for recreating objects in another DB?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy to migrate data from one DB to another (SQLite to MySQL). Leaving all the DDL-related stuff behind (as it is a different topic), I'm trying to get results from one Engine->Connection->Session->Query and add them into another DB Engine->Connection->Session.

Let's say this is my starter code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

source_engine = create_engine(args.source_db_dsn)
source_session_maker = sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                    autoflush=False,
                                    bind=source_engine.connect())

dest_engine = create_engine(args.dest_db_dsn)
dest_session_maker = sessionmaker(autocommit=True,
                                  autoflush=True,
                                  bind=dest_engine.connect())

Base = declarative_base()
class Customer(Base):
    __tablename__ = "customer"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255))
    description = Column(String(255))

with source_session_maker() as source_session:

    query = source_session.query(Customer)

    with dest_session_maker.begin() as dest_session:
        dest_session.query(Customer).delete()
```

So now we have a clean table that is ready to accept new rows.

Here are nearly all the cases I've tried:

1. This will throw an Exception as objects are attached to the first Session:

```
dest_session.add_all(query.all())
```

2. This runs very slow as Load=True will ask for each distinct record

```
dest_session.merge_results(query, Load=True)
```

3. This will not add anything as all the objects are still "persistent" after moving from one Session to another

```
dest_session.merge_results(query, Load=False)
```

4. This works and works fast, but using underscored properties doesn't look legal to me (is it really OK?). Beside that, we have an unnecessary Object->dict->Object conversion

```
dest_session.bulk_insert_mappings(Customer,
                                          (o.__dict__ for o in query.all()))
```

I also tried to call .clean(), .refresh_all(), .populate_existing() but the only thing that did the "persistent" flag to be cleared was calling .merge() with the Load=True.

I guess that being able to clear the persistent state on merged objects would be most elegant way, but I have not found any way to manipulate the state in SQLAlchemy docs (cause it may not be the best idea, and the framework tries to keep you out from such things.)

What do you guys think would be the best option to add a bunch of objects from one DB Query into another's DB Session?

Comment: It sounds to me like you are reinventing the wheel. Surely there must be a database migration tool out there that can migrate SQLite to MySQL.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon. Surely, there are. I just want to know SQLAlchemy a bit better.